# How to click into toggle button using appium and java?

Tags: selenium, appium, ui-automation, togglebutton

I'm using java with TestNG Framework with Appium to test a site on safari browser in Ipad simulator , i want to know how to identify toggle button and to make it ON / OFF.

Here Html code :

```
  <md-switch aria-label="alertToMail" ng-model="mail" class="ticket-switch ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="md-container"><div class="md-bar"></div><div class="md-thumb-container"><div class="md-thumb md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""></div></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="md-label"> </div></md-switch>
```

[image: toggle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than i thought just locate element `By.className("ng-empty")` or `By.className("ng-not-empty")` depending on some conditions (element ON or OFF) and then the action with `.click();`